# How to create new SDK using another one in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating new SDK using another one, when i am trying to build SDK its successfully build but when i am to using this SDK in my new Apps its crashing on runtime

There are my app level gradle below and i have mention another SDK

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
     rules.pro'
       }
     }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':aeps_lib-release')

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

here i am mention my app level grdale screenshot
 [image]

there are my new apps app level as in screenshot

[image]

when ever i am trying to call services that are in another SDK with the help of my own SDK its creashing and i am getting error

here is the my logcat error

```
    --------- beginning of crash
    2020-03-07 14:55:16.515 2897-2897/com.app.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
    main
    Process: com.app.testapp, PID: 2897
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lexample/com/aeps_lib/AepsHome;
    at com.app.services.AEPSService.mCallexample(AEPSService.java:43)
    at com.app.services.AEPSService.onCreate(AEPSService.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
    (TransactionExecutor.java:113)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
    (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
    "example.com.aeps_lib.AepsHome" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
     "/data/app/com.app.testapp- 
    0ILJojEWHa8rcY3DWG2gVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.testapp- 
    0ILJojEWHa8rcY3DWG2gVw==/lib/arm, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.app.services.AEPSService.mCallexample(AEPSService.java:43) 
    at com.app.services.AEPSService.onCreate(AEPSService.java:37) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at 

    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
    (TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922) 
    2020-03-07 14:55:16.750 2897-2897/com.app.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2897 
    SIG: 9
```

Comment: are you using .jar files for SDK?

Comment: @pawan soni i am using .aar file

Comment: change build gradle line for SDK -  implementation files('libs/"file_name".aar')